# Is there a better way to size a buffer for printing integers?

Tags: c, printf, buffer

I want to create a buffer for `sprintf`ing a integer (in this case an `unsigned int`). A simple and misguided approach would be:

```
char buf[11];

sprintf(buf, "%u", x);
```

This works great if we know that `unsigned int` is at most `33` bits wide, but what if we want to accomodate all wierd architectures? The best I can come up with is:

```
char buf[(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned)+5)/3];

sprintf(buf, "%u", x);
```

I'm quite confident this will work on any implementation. `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned)` is (an upper bound for) the number of bits in an `unsigned`. Then I add two and divide 3 to find the number of digits in octal representation and finally add one for the NUL-termination. This means the buffer is enough for printing the number in octal and since decimal representation uses no more digits than octal it will be enough for decimal representation too.

Is there a better way to do this? By better I mean a way producing smaller buffer without risking a buffer overrun no matter what value `x` has (even in face of malicious constructed yet standard conforming implementation). My approach would produce a 12-`char` buffer for 32-bit `unsigned` despite the fact that `11` would be enough.

Comment: "Then I add two and divide 3 to find the number of digits in octal representation"  Eh... what? Why? Do you want the number to be printed with any base or with octal base specifically, or what? Please clarify.

Comment: There is a similar question on Math SE:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-decimal-digits-for-a-binary-number

Comment: @KlasLindbäck No that's not a duplicate because we can't tell how the question here even makes sense. "char buf[11];" ... "This works great if we know that unsigned int is at most 33 bits wide" means that binary notation isn't desired here.

Comment: @anonymoose (N+2)/3+1 = (N+5)/3

Comment: @anonymoose happens... :) try writing it down with a pen and paper....

Comment: @Lundin Exactly what is it you don't think makes sense with the question? My comment about 33bits means that `x` would be at most `8589934591` which means that the `sprintf` would need to print no more than `10` digits and one terminating NUL.

Comment: @skyking Where does the octal come from? You just drop that out of the blue. `%u` will give decimal representation, period. If you want octal, you would use `%o`. If you want any base, you would use some entirely different kind of code.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, n binary digits require ceil(n*ln(2)/ln(10)) ≈ ceil(n * 0.301) decimal digits (not counting the terminating NUL character).

Comment: @Lundin Octal representation of a number uses no fewer digits than a decimal representation. Consequently ensuring that the buffer is large enough to hold the octal representation will make it enough to hold the decimal representation of the number. In the above case I want decimal representation of `x`.

Comment: @skyking **Why do you want support for octal representation**? In a buffer that supposed to hold the result of `sprintf(buf, "%u", x);`. This is just nonsense.

Comment: @Lundin I haven't said I want to support octal representation. I want `buf` to be large enough to be guaranteed that `sprintf` won't overflow. The reason for octal representation in the reasoning is that it will produce an upper bound for the number of characters required for the decimal representation.  The question is if somebody have a better solution that doesn't reserve about 10% more memory than actually required.

Comment: 'char buf[256];`. By the time this is an actual problem you'll be dead and it's somebody elses problem. Alternatively. Extrapolate how often we double the number of bits in integers, aim for the buffer running out some time just before your retirement and you have a nice retirement insurance.

Comment: 10% unnecessary memory is 1 byte. May I suggest something like `#if UINT_MAX <= ... ` etc? Then you can move on to something worthwhile.

Comment: What @Art says.  Why are you worrying about this?   If you have a bug shortage, I have plenty going spare;)   Unless you are running on some RAM-constrained embedded system, just go with 256, or 512, or whatever that is guaranteed much too big.  Move on the the next problem.

Comment: @Lundin The question made sense to me. The question is: "How many decimal digits are needed to represent a binary unsigned number with N bits?" The linked question seems to address that.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck the question is 'Is there a better way to size a buffer for printing integers?'.  The answer is 'sure, make it so large that it doesn't matter what the format is'.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I was perhaps a bit unclear what I meant by "better". In this case smaller is better so just picking a buffer size as you and Art suggested is not considered better in this case.

Comment: Your question here, your time thinking about it, this discussion, etc. has already used more CPU power and bytes than any shrinkage of a buffer would ever save. Especially considering that the buffer size will most likely be rounded up to 16 or even 32 to keep proper stack alignment.

Comment: @art I can see buffer size optimization real in 2 cases: arrays/structures that need to accommodate a string containing an `unsigned` as there  may be many instances of the object, Embedded applications where memory needs are sometimes _very_ tight.  Yet for a single integer, of some type, to text, `char s[CHAR_BIT*sizeof(integer)+2]` will handle every real platform, base and sign-ness I can reasonable think off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling different relevant comments, most notably:

- the [math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-decimal-digits-for-a-binary-number).
- [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)'s comment that summarizes it well: *“n binary digits require ceil(n*ln(2)/ln(10)) ≈ ceil(n * 0.301)”*

You have your answer:

```
#define MAX_DECIMAL_SIZE(x)  ((size_t)(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(x) * 302 / 1000) + 1)

char buffer[MAX_DECIMAL_SIZE(unsigned int) + 1];
sprintf(buffer, "%u", x);

/* MAX_DECIMAL_SIZE(uint8_t) => 3
 * MAX_DECIMAL_SIZE(uint16_t) => 5
 * MAX_DECIMAL_SIZE(uint32_t) => 10
 * MAX_DECIMAL_SIZE(uint64_t) => 20
 * MAX_DECIMAL_SIZE(__uint128_t) => 39 */
```

The `302/1000` comes from `ln(2)/ln(10)`, rounded up. You can take more digits, from `0.3010299956639812…` for more precision, but that's overkill until you work with 32768-bits systems or so. Continued fractions work too (see Martin R's comment below). Either way, be careful that `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(x) * <your chosen numerator>` is not too large and remember the result must be greater than the actual value.

And if you really insist on octal representation, just change the multiplier to `ln(2)/ln(8)` (that's ⅓) and you'll have the number of octal digits required.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but 16/53 ≈ 0.30188 is an even better approximation with smaller numerator/denominator (obtained using continued fractions :)

Comment: Indeed, added a note. Either way, magic numbers like this would need to be duly commented.

Comment: Yes, with my last update to the question there's a possibility that the expression overflows. While a smaller factor mitigates the possibility the expression is not immune to that, but I think that can be accomplished by ensuring the expression will have large enough type (by using factors of carefully chosen types).

Comment: @skyking> Using a compiler on a 32-bit system, the macro I made will not overflow unless you have 7million-bit integers on your target platform. I assume by the time this happens you should have upgraded to a 64-bit compiler and be good for 30-quadrillon-bit architectures.

Comment: I'd prefer `#define DECIMAL_DIGITS(x) ((CHAR_BIT * sizeof (x) * 28) / 93 + 2)`. 28/93 ≈ 0.301075, which is a slightly better approximation for (while still being greater than) log(2)/log(10); the `+2` part includes both rounding (+1) and possible sign, just because it is so easy to accidentally forget to include in the computation. The buffer would then be `char buffer[DECIMAL_DIGITS(x) + 1];`, where the +1 is for the terminating nul byte.

Comment: @NominalAnimal> yeah, Martin R also suggested using continued fractions. You may pick any fraction you like as long as it's greater than than the actual value. I chose to left out the sign because OP used `%u`, which implies unsignedness. For a signed value I'd add 1 to the result but substract 1 from bit number.

Comment: There is nothing in the C language development that indicates that `int` will ever become larger than 4 bytes. Should 128 bit computers get invented, they would probably rather come up with a `long long long`... Or more sanely, an `uint128_t`. So all of these theories are completely useless, for now. Instead, focus on support for computers that exist in the real world.

Comment: @Lundin> Macro does not work with only int, it works with any unsigned numeral type. Should there be a `long long long long int`, it would get the size right as well. And right now in real world, there are at least uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t and __uint128_t, and the macro gets all of those right.

Comment: @spectras In which case you can as well do `sizeof(x)/2 * 5`, to cover all known computers in the real world.

Comment: @Lundin: The macro works with any integer type `x` and any variable `x` of any integer type, not just `int`. A careless programmer might change the type to some `hugeint_t`. I like the macro, because it is **safe**, and should get evaluated at compile time anyway (at least with GCC and optimizations enabled). Note that I also prefer as descriptive name for the macro as possible.

Comment: @NominalAnimal If some careless programmer changes the types to something completely bananas, they won't get much in the way of sane output from the buffer designed to hold an decimal integer in string format, now would they? This is actually the reason why the macro is _unsafe_ - it isn't idiot-proof.

Comment: @Lundin: It depends. Buffer overrun problems are the most typical ones I see in the wild. It is easy to notice that the printf conversion pattern is incorrect, and even an idiot probably notices to fix that.  In my case, I like the macro a lot, because it gives new programmers a pause: *"Why does this code use a macro in the buffer size declaration?"*. The macro name is an important clue there. Now, if they after that realization still often create buffer overrun bugs, it's on them: at least I tried to help them learn. This is the logic I apply for these types of cases.

Comment: @Lundin> basically you're just suggesting the **exact same approach** except you approximated `8 * ln(2) / ln(10)` to `5 / 2 = 2.5` instead of `8 * 302/1000 = 2.416` (or `8 * 28 / 93 ≈ 2.4086` for NominalAnimal's version) , I don't really see your point or how that makes it any safer. It does break it on systems that have non-8-bit chars though, such as C54x DSPs.

Comment: @spectras People who try to write C code portable to various obsolete Texas DSPs deserve all the bugs they can get. I doubt anyone ever wrote C code for those anyhow, since DSP programmers tend to be fixated with assembler. Why do you need a string handling program to be portable to obsolete DSPs?

Comment: Concern about naming. "Size" tends to refer to the size of the needed buffer and "length" to the length as returned by `strlen()`.  To that end, I recommend using `MAX_DECIMAL_LENGTH(x) ((size_t)(CHAR_BIT * ...` and `MAX_DECIMAL_SIZE(x) (MAX_DECIMAL_LENGTH(x) + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with dynamically allocated memory, you can use `asprintf` instead.  This function will allocate the proper amount of memory to hold the string.

```
char *buf;
int result = asprintf(&buf, "%u", x);
if (result == -1) {
    perror("asprintf failed");
} else {
    ...
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: It is very convenient, alas it's not part of C standard, not even of POSIX, it's a pure GNU extension. Handy when you target GNU systems though.

Comment: You can take the return value of `snprintf` and then allocate the appropriate amount if you want to only use the standard library

Comment: @ErikW True about `snprintf()`, yet pedantic code needs to look for encoding error returns and locale issues.

Answer (score 0):

If the array should work on all real-world computers, then `int` can either be 2 or 4 bytes. No other alternatives exist (*).

Meaning the maximum value it can hold is either 65535 or 4.29*10^9. Which in turn means that your array needs to hold either 5 or 10 digits.

Which in turn means that the array could be declared as:

```
 char buf [sizeof(int)/2 * 5 + 1];
```

which will either expand to 5+1 or 10+1, which covers all known computers in the world.

A better and more professional solution is to use the fixed-width types from `stdint.h`. Then always you know in advance exactly how many digits that is needed, portably, and can therefore get rid of the above "magic numbers".

---

(*) In C language standard theory, an `int` could be anything 2 bytes or larger. But since no such systems will ever exist in the real world, there is no point in making your code portable to them. The C language has already introduced `long` and `long long` for a reason.

People who are concerned about portability to wildly exotic, completely fictional systems are misguided, they are mostly C language lawyers who like posing. You should not let such theoretical nonsense affect how you write professional programs for real-world computers.

---

EDIT

The "C language-lawyer poser" version would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define GET_SIZE(n) sizeof(STRINGIFY(n))
#define DIGITS(type) _Generic((type), unsigned int: GET_SIZE(INT_MAX) )

int main(void) 
{
  unsigned int x;
  char buf [DIGITS(x)];

  printf("%zu", sizeof(buf));

  return 0;
}
```

Note that this assumes that `INT_MAX` expands to an integer constant and not to an expression. I got really strange results from GCC when using `UINT_MAX`, because that macro is defined as an expression internally, inside limits.h.

Comment: I agree with your answer, except the last paragraph. Even though I prefer a macro in the buffer size argument, it is not because I assume portability; it is because I think it makes the code easier to manage, and especially if used in code read by new programmers, might help them learn to avoid buffer overrun problems -- which are woefully common in C.  I might be posing, and it is pretty much theoretical, but I'm definitely not a language lawyer! (The edited example is just trolling, though. Only an idiot would write *that*.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal It is no less trolling than the "logarithmic" answer.

Comment: You did not explain where your magic `5 / 2` factor comes from, if not from approximating `CHAR_BIT * ln(2) / ln(10)`. Fact is you do the exact same thing, you just hard-coded the CHAR_BIT value to 8 and used a less accurate approximation you got through trial and error instead of understanding the underlying formula. It falls short (or long, haha) on `__uint128_t` by the way.

Comment: @spectras "Which in turn means that your array needs to hold either 5 or 10 digits." Simply count the digits needed for the numbers posted before that sentence. The initial part of this answer focuses on answering the question, which is only concerned about `unsigned int`. Therefore `uint128_t` and other such things that weren't mentioned in the question, are not addressed. The last snippet can be expanded to cover other types, by adding them to the _Generic list.

Comment: (Second example just plain doesn't work by the way, because none of the `*_MAX` macros expand to just a literal integer on my system. My limits.h has parenthesizes around the values - but I take the example was for joke value anyway).

Answer (score 0):

The cases where something like this is needed is rare: perhaps some microcontroller code, transferring a value over some serial protocol. In such cases, using any of the `printf()` family of functions may increase the size of the final binary.

(In typical C development environments, the C library is dynamically loaded, and there is absolutely no benefit in trying to avoid standard C library functions. It will not decrease the program size.)

So, if I needed such code, I might write a header file,

```
#if defined(INTTYPE) && defined (UINTTYPE) && defined (FUNCNAME)

#ifndef DECIMAL_DIGITS_IN
#define DECIMAL_DIGITS_IN(x) ((CHAR_BIT * sizeof (x) * 28) / 93 + 2)
#endif

char *FUNCNAME(const INTTYPE value)
{
    static char buffer[DECIMAL_DIGITS_IN(value) + 1];
    char       *p = buffer + sizeof buffer;
    UINTTYPE    left = (value < 0) ? -value : value;

    *(--p) = '\0';
    do {
        *(--p) = '0' + (left % 10);
        left /= 10;
    } while (left > 0);

    if (value < 0)
        *(--p) = '-';

    return p;
}

#undef FUNCNAME
#undef INTTYPE
#undef UINTTYPE

#endif
```

and for each type I'd need, I'd use

```
#define FUNCNAME int2str
#define INTTYPE  int
#define UINTTYPE unsigned int
#include "above.h"
```

---

In more ordinary code, the best approach is to use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to avoid buffer overruns, with the buffer size "guesstimated". For example,

```
unsigned int x;

char  buffer[256];
int   len;

len = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "Message with a number %u", x);
if (len < 0 || (size_t)len >= sizeof buffer - 1) {
    /* Abort! The buffer was (almost certainly) too small! */
} else {
    /* Success; we have the string in buffer[]. */
}
```

Whether `buffer[]` is a few dozen or even few hundred bytes larger than necessary, is **completely irrelevant** in typical programs.  Just make it large enough, and output an error message in the error case that tells which buffer (file and function) was not long enough, so it'll be easy to fix in the unlikely case it ever is too short.

---

As mentioned by [dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44025682/1475978), `asprintf()` GNU extension is a viable alternative. It returns a dynamically allocated string.

Outside of GNU systems -- and this is what I suggest OP considers, too -- one can implement their own `asprintf()`, using 
[`vsnprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/vsnprintf.3p.html) (available in C99 and later C libraries, and also in POSIX.1 C libraries).

I prefer the variant that acts like POSIX.1 getline(), i.e. takes pointers to a pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer and the size of that buffer as extra parameters, and resizes that buffer if necessary:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

size_t dynamic_printf(char **dataptr, size_t *sizeptr, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_arg  args;
    char   *data;
    size_t  size;
    int     len;

    if (!dataptr || !sizeptr || !format) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    }
    if (!*sizeptr) {
        *dataptr = NULL;
        *sizeptr = 0;
    }
    data = *dataptr;
    size = *sizeptr;

    va_start(args, format);
    len = vsnprintf(data, size, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    if (len < 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    } else
    if ((size_t)len < size) {
        errno = 0;
        return (size_t)len;
    }

    /* Need to reallocate the buffer. */
    size = (size_t)len + 1;
    data = realloc(data, size);
    if (!data) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return 0;
    }
    *dataptr = data;
    *sizeptr = size;

    va_start(args, format);
    len = vsnprintf(data, size, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    if (len != (int)(size - 1)) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    }

    errno = 0;
    return (size_t)len;
}
```

The idea is that you can reuse the same dynamic buffer across several `dynamic_printf()` calls:

```
    char   *data = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;
    size_t  len;

    /* Some kind of loop for example */

        len = dynamic_printf(&data, &size, "This is something I need in a buffer");
        if (errno) {
            /* Abort! Reason is strerror(errno) */
        } else {
            /* data is non-NULL, and has len chars in it. */
        }

    /* Strings are no longer used, so free the buffer */
    free(data);
    data = NULL;
    size = 0;
```

Note that it is perfectly safe to run `free(data); data = NULL; size = 0;` between calls. `free(NULL)` does nothing, and if the buffer pointer is `NULL` and size zero, the function will just dynamically allocate a new buffer.

In the worst case (when the buffer is not long enough), the function does "print" the string twice. This is perfectly acceptable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

OP's solution minimally meets design goals.

> Is there a better way to size a buffer for printing integers?

Even a short analysis indicates the the number of bits needed with a `unsigned` grows by a factor of  `log10(2)` or about 0.30103.... for each value bit when printing decimal and by `1/3` for printing octal.  OP's code uses a factor of one-third or 0.33333...

```
unsigned x;
char buf[(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned)+5)/3];
sprintf(buf, "%u", x);
```

Considerations:

1. If buffer tightness concerns are real, then a buffer for decimal printing deserves a separate consideration than printing in octal.
2. Correctness:  Unless code uses a strange *locale* with `sprintf()`, the conversion of the widest `unsigned`, which is `UINT_MAX` works for all platforms.
3. Clarity: the `...5)/3` is unadorned and does not indicate the rational for 5 and 3.
4. Efficiency.  The buffer size is modestly excessive.  This would not be an issues for a single buffer, but for an array of buffers a tighter value is recommended.
5. Generality: macro is crafted to only one type.
6. Potential hazard:  With code re-use, a code extrapolation could use the same 5 and 3 for `int` without due consideration.  OP's 5/3 works for `int` too, so this is not an issue.
7. Corner case: Using 5/3 for *signed* types and octal is a problem as `(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned)+5)/3` should be `(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned) + 5)/3 + 1`.  Example: problem occurs when trying to convert an `int -32768` to base 8 text: "-100000" via some function (not `sprintf(... "%o" ...)`).  That buffer needed is 8 where as `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned)+5)/3` could be 7.

---

> Is there a better way to do this?

Candidate for base 10:

28/93 (0.301075...) is a very close, and greater, approximation of log10(2).  Of course code could use a more obvious fraction like 30103/100000.

Generality: A good macro would also adapt to other types.  Below is one for various unsigned types.

```
#define LOG10_2_N 28
#define LOG10_2_D 93
//                              1 for the ceiling                          1 for \0
#define UINT_BUFFER10_SIZE(type) (1 + (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)*LOG10_2_N)/LOG10_2_D + 1)


unsigned x;
char bufx[UINT_BUFFER10_SIZE(x)];
sprintf(bufx, "%u", x);

size_t z;
char bufz[UINT_BUFFER10_SIZE(z)];
sprintf(bufz, "%zu", z);
```

The 28/93 fraction give the same answer integer results as log10(2) for integer sizes 1 to 92 bits and so is space efficient for arrays of buffers.  It is never too small.

A macro for signed type could use

```
#define INT_BUFFER_SIZE(type) (1+1+ (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)-1)*LOG10_2_N)/LOG10_2_D + 1)
```

Avoid an off-by-one issue: I recommend using `SIZE` in the macro name to convey the buffer *size* needed and not the maximum string length.

Candidate for base 8:

Once a computed size for non-base 10 is needed, applications I've made usually need a a buffer to handle any base 2 and up.  Consider `printf()` may allow `%b` someday too.  So for a *general* purpose buffer to handle integer to text, any base, any sign-ness suggest:

```
#define INT_STRING_SIZE(x)  (1 /* sign */ + CHAR_BIT*sizeof(x) + 1 /* \0 */)

int x = INT_MIN;
char buf[INT_STRING_SIZE(x)];
my_itoa(buf, sizeof buf, x, 2);
puts(buf); --> "-10000000000000000000000000000000"  (34 char were needed)
```