# Checking the validity of a string representing a number

Tags: c

I need to write a function which will check a string for a few properties:

1. The string must represent a positive integer (> 0)
2. The integer mustn't require more than 32 bits of memory
3. There are no letters in the string

If these conditions are met, it should return the string as an int, if any of these conditions are not met, it should return -1.

Currently the function fails to deal with the following 2 inputs:

- `4y`
- `13.4`

If my `isDigit()` loop works as intended it'd be able to check for them. Why does the loop not work?

```
int convert(const char length[]) {
  long input = atol(length);
  if (input >= 2147483648 || input <= 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  int chkr = 0;
  while (chkr < strlen(length)) {
    if (isdigit(length[chkr++]) == 0) {
      return -1;
   }
    else {
      return atoi(length);
    }
  }
  input = atol(length);
  if (length[0] == '0') {
    return -1;
  }
  if (strlen(length) < 3) {
    return -1;
  }
 else {
    return atoi(len gth);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `strtol` for this. Also please show some examples of valid and invalid strings

Comment: And please tll us what a "3 integer string" is.

Comment: I'd suggest that `length` is not a good name for a string generally - certainly in the context of the code provided.

Comment: learn to use your debugger.

Comment: **Never** use `atol()` (or `atoi()` or `atoll()`).  From [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html): "... `atoi()` **does not detect errors**."

Comment: @Jabberwocky for example the wider programme would be called:
./triangle 1 2 3
at which point the above function convert would be called on each number in the string individually:
convert(inputstr[n])

Comment: @pm100 the code compiles fine, it simply doesn't function as I'd want it to and I can't work out why

Comment: @Alex take a look at my answer. You can omit most of your code.

Comment: @Alex - thats exactly what a debugger is for, code that compiles but doesnt do what you want

Comment: I'd recommend allowing (0 to many white spaces)(optional + sign)[digits maybe with many leading zeros](0 to many white spaces). And value < 2^32.  So far no answer handles that.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846908/2410359

Comment: Slould leading white space be allowed?

Comment: Should trailing whitespace be allowed?

Comment: Should `"+123"` be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is terribly convoluted and wrong.

Use this instead and let the C library do the dirty work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// The function you're interested in

int convert(const char string[]) {
  char *endptr;
  if (!isdigit((unsigned char)string[0]))
    return -1;

  errno = 0;    // need to set errno to 0 (see errno documentation)
  long value = strtol(string, &endptr, 10);
  if (errno != 0 || value <= 0 || value > 2147483647 || *endptr != 0)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  return value;
}

int main() {
  // Test different cases:

  struct {
    const char *input;
    int expected;
  } testcases[] =
  {
    // OK cases
    "123", 123,
    "1234", 1234,
    "2147483647", 2147483647,

    // fail cases
    "-1234", -1,      // number is negatif
    "12.3", -1,       // contains non digit '.'
    "123y", -1,       // contains non digit 'y'
    "2147483648", -1, // out of range
    " 123", -1,      // starts with a space

    // wrong test case on purpose
    "1234", 1245,
  };

  // Test all test cases

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(testcases) / sizeof(testcases[0]); i++)
  {
    int value = convert(testcases[i].input);
    if (value != testcases[i].expected)
    {
      printf("convert(\"%s\") failed, returned value = %d, expected value = %d\n", testcases[i].input, value, testcases[i].expected);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("convert(\"%s\") passed\n", testcases[i].input);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The program prints every test case. The last test case is wrong on purpose.

The for loop loops through a number of test cases and for each test case that fails it prints the values involved.

Output:

```
convert("123") passed
convert("1234") passed
convert("2147483647") passed
convert("-1234") passed
convert("12.3") passed
convert("123y") passed
convert("2147483648") passed
convert("1234") failed, returned value = 1234, expected value = 1245
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking the first character and immediately return after that.

```
input = atol(length);
```

is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this loop:

```
while (chkr < strlen(length)) {
    if (isdigit(length[chkr++]) == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return atoi(length);
    }
}
```

You're not going through the whole string, you're returning after the first char anyway. You don't want to return in the `else` case here, otherwise that's skipping the rest of your program. Just have this:

```
while (chkr < strlen(length)) {
    if (isdigit(length[chkr++]) == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

After that, this line here

```
input = atol(length);
```

Is not needed. Input had that value anyway. It's not causing any harm, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply on tidying up the code. Although the function is now simpler, it now fails to convert any input string into an output number...

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks to everyone for all of the discussion. Feel like I've learnt an absolute shedload and my problem's been solved!

Comment: isdigit expects a value in the unsigned char range or EOF.  With char, code risks UB.  'isdigit((unsigned char) length[...])' is prudent.

Comment: This will fail on "4000000000".

Answer (score 0):

```
int convert(const char length[]) {
    if (atol(length) >= 2147483648 || atol(length) <= 0)
        return -1;

    int chkr = 0;
    while (chkr < strlen (length)) {
        if (isdigit(length[chkr++]) == 0)
            return -1;
    }

    return atoi(length);
}
```

**Edit**: Fixed answer. No clue why I didn't use isdigit().
Was trying too hard to be clever and it backfired, I guess.

Comment: So why don't you let the compiler do the work for you and write `'0'` instead of `48` and `'9'` instead of `57`?

Comment: Badly reinventing the [standard C `isdigit()` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.5) is a really misguided - at best - idea.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks to everyone for all of the discussion. Feel like I've learnt an absolute shedload and my problem's been solved!

Comment: 1) isdigit not coded well for char < 0.       2) does not accept "+123".

Comment: Question asks for positive integers. Neither would I accept +123.

Comment: When `long` is 32 bit, this can fail for `convert("5000000000"), convert("15000000000")`, many others.  `atol()` is UB on overflow.

Comment: `char < 0` is  about UB when calling `isdigit(int ch)` with a character with a negative value.  Consider `"123\x80"`.  This code calls `isdigit()` with a negative value when `char` is _signed_.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before your `while` loop returns after the first iteration.

Use `sscanf` instead of `atol` or `atoi`. This is preferable as you can detect errors:

```
int convert(const char *length){
    int err, sz;
    unsigned rtn;
    /*%u reads an unsigned integer (mostly 32 bit) >= 0*/
    err = sscanf(length, "%u%n", &rtn, &sz);
    /*check reading error occured*/
    if(err == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    /*check if there is no whitespace/sign*/
    if(!isdigit(length[0])){
        return -1;
    }
    /*check if 0 < rtn <= INT_MAX*/
    if(rtn <= 0 || rtn > INT_MAX){
        return -1;
    }
    /*check everything got read*/
    /*=> no letters*/
    if(sz != strlen(length)){
        return -1;
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

Let's test it:

```
/*these fail*/
const char zero[] = "0";
const char spaceStart[] = " 84654";
const char spaceEnd[] = "84654 ";
const char negative[] = "-7869";
const char tooBig[] = "2147483648";
const char fitsInto32BitInt[] = "2147483647";
const char positive[] = "+7526";
const char withLetter[] = "4y";
const char withPoint[] = "13.4";
/*these work*/
const char one[] = "1";
const char fine[] = "746838";
const char fitsInto32BitInt[] = "2147483647";
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", convert("5000000000"));` returns `705032704`,  I'd expect OP would want `-1`.  The point, on scanning a text to save in an `unsigned` with `"%u"`, overflow is _undefined behavior_.  `"%u"` is reasonable but not robust.