# Function fgets doesn't store string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, filesystems

so I want to create an address book program and I have this following code :

```
#define MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS 1000

int i = 0 ;
int answer = 0 ;
int number_of_people = 0 ;

FILE* address_book = NULL ;

address_book = fopen("addressBook.txt", "w")  ;

typedef struct People People ;

struct People
{
    char f_name[MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS]
};

People *persons = NULL ;

printf("A D D R R E S S  B O O K \n\n\n") ;

printf("1. Add a new contact \n") ;
printf("2. View all contacts \n") ;
printf("\nMake your choice : ") ;

while (answer < 1 || answer > 2)
{
    printf("\nWrong input, try again ! : ") ;
    scanf("%d", &answer) ;
}

if (answer == 1)
{
    printf("How many contacts do you want to add ? : ") ;
    scanf("%d", &number_of_people) ;

    persons = malloc(number_of_people * sizeof(People) ) ;

    if (persons == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nMemory allocation failed !") ;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < number_of_people; i++)
    {
        printf("Person %d ", (i+1)) ;
        printf("Enter the first name : ") ;
        fgets(persons[i].f_name, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, stdin) ;

        if (address_book == NULL)
        {
        printf("\nFailed to open file ! ") ;
        }

    fputs(persons[i].f_name, address_book) ;
    fputc('\n', address_book) ;

    }
}
```

My problem is that the program doesn't want to store the first name ( the "fgets" calling line).
It diplays what is in the printf("Enter you first name : ") ;
And ignores the following line ( fgets(persons[i].f_name..) , 
After that it goes directly to the end of the program
Help please

Comment: Okay i see now, thanks

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  How do you expect us to reproduce the problem so we can help you debug it.  Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using both `fgets()` and `scanf()` on the same stream.

After `scanf("%d", &answer)` reads the numeric text and forms an `int`, the following <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.  [@xing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064440/function-fgets-doesnt-store-string/54065309#comment94962117_54064440)

Later, `fgets(persons[i].f_name,...` simple read that remaining `'\n'` as the input for the first name.

---

Various solutions:

A) After `scanf("%d", &answer);` read remaining characters in the line

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && ch != EOF) {
  ;
}
```

B) Use `fgets()` to read the `answer`

```
char buf[50];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
answer = atoi(buf);
```

C) Use `fgets()` robustly: [`int my_get_int(int *i)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846908/2410359)

```
if (my_get_int(&answer) == 1) {
  // Success
}
```

Comment: Sir, I've seen your lots of brilliant answers. Could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076333/subset-sum-overlapping-dilemma-recursively/54076547 ??

Comment: @chux I understand better know how both scanf and fgets are working, thanks. I tried all of your solutions and they are all working, but can you explain me more the A and the C ones ?

Comment: @TonyStark A) Example: you enter 4 keys `"123\"`, `scanf("%d", &answer);` will consume the `"123"`, leaving the `"\n"` for the next input operation.  A following `fgets()` will read the then short remaining line as `"\n"`.  If in between, code does A), then all the characters after the `"123"` up to and including the `"\n"` are read - and discarded.  Then the following `fgets()` will no get the "\n"`, but read in the next line of input (the first name).

Comment: @TonyStark C) Refer to the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846908/2410359) and comment there about any details needed there.