# Subset sum overlapping dilemma recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I'm studying recursive logic that one of the problems is subset sum. AFAI read, there are overlaps when it is run by recursion. But, I cannot figure out how there are. Also, I read that to overcome the issue DP can be used but I want to comprehend ***how the recursion overcome the problem.*** Could you picturize an example with overlapping?

Pseudo-code,

```
def hasSum( array, start, sum):
   if sum == 0:
       return true

   if start > array.length - 1:
       return false;

   return hasSum(array, start + 1, sum - array[start])
           or hasSum(array, start + 1, sum)
```

I cannot associate the logic with the following picture, I'm certainly overlook a point / points.

[image]

Comment: [1, 3, 1, 8] -> you will eventually use first 1 and 3, then not use second 1 and have a sum of 4. On another case you will use only the second 1 and the 3 so you also end up with a sum of 4 in a different way. There is a solution for one of those cases only if there is a solution for the other one, hence the overlap

Comment: The logic in the code does not match with the picture

Comment: @dheiberg seemingly, I'm not the only student having difficulty in understanding recursion rightly. Thanks for the comment making me feel better.

Comment: Picture is fine if your array is [1,2,3]. On each step you are deciding to add or not to add the current element to your sum, in the image instead of sum it is showing the elements added for the sum. You end up with every possible subset, which means having made the sum of every possible subset. The overlap comes from when you end up with same sum remaining at the same index.

Comment: @juvian I don't figure out _The overlap comes from when you end up with same sum remaining at the same index._ case. Could you make it clearer a bit more?

Comment: @concurrencyboy already gave example on first comment. Note that in your recurssion, if you problem was hasSum(array, 0, 10) then a possible subproblem is hasSum(array, 5, 3). Depending on the numbers of array, it is possible that hasSum(array, 5, 3) is called multiple times, because there are multiple ways of summing 7 with the first 5 array elements.

Comment: Your picture asks many times whether a given integer is "in the set".  However, there is no set in your posted code.  The picture steps through integers from 1 to some unexplained limit; this iteration is not reflected in the code.  You need to bring your code and your documentation into sync before we can properly understand your confusion.

Comment: Among other things, we expect to see that you've made a substantive attempt to understand your problem.  This would include posting a working example with some sort of trace.  If nothing else, insert simple `print` statements to trace the logic and data flow.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 0):

There is overlap caused by this line here:

```
return hasSum(array, start + 1, sum - array[start])
           or hasSum(array, start + 1, sum)
```

If the algorithm doesn't find a valid condition with the first `hasSum` (which because of recursion has already gone through the entire array by the time is returns to this point), it will try again with the second `hasSum` which ignores the value of this current index. This means that the algorithm checks the same indexes multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the explanation is way too shallow. It is not to grasp the crux point of "recurrence"

Comment: Are you trying to understand how the algorithm actually works? It is a fairly simple algorithm, would be easy to dry run on paper with a small array of 4 numbers and a simple sum.

Comment: simple algorithm ?? simple algorithm ?? I've read the keywords thrice. A thing in only one line doesn't mean simple. **“Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.” — Leonardo da Vinci**. Good luck to you!

Comment: By 'simple' I mean there are few lines of code and not many branching options. Therefore if you were to try to run it through on paper with the example [1, 3, 1] and sum 4, you will be able to see the logic for yourself. Alternatively, using an IDE and stepping through the code as it is executing is also a great way to see what it is doing at each step. I can attempt to explain the algorithm in words, but you are keen on having some diagram which is easiest done with pen and paper unfortunately.