# Convert uint8_t to an ascii string C

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, uart

Given the following function

```
UART_write(UART_Handle handle, const void *buffer, size_t size);
```

I want to send via uart a int8_t value  ( log it )

What i tried:

```
int8_t value;
UART_write(uart, value, strlen(value));
```

---

```
const char *echoPrompt = (char *)value;
UART_write(uart, echoPrompt, sizeof(echoPrompt));
```

---

```
const char echoPrompt2[] = {value};
UART_write(uart, echoPrompt2, sizeof(echoPrompt2));
```

---

```
const char* buff = value;
UART_write(uart, value, strlen(value));
```

The best i got is logging the hex value

Exemple of how the uart_write function works: In orded to log "12" what I need to do is

```
   const uint8_t value[] = {0x31, 0x32};
   UART_write(uart, value, sizeof(value));
```

So my question is, how to log my int8_t variable  ( I need to log negative numbers as well)

Comment: Did you [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Convert+uint8_t+to+an+ascii+string+C+site%3Astackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to convert your integer to string.

`snprintf` is a standard way to do this, if your libc provides it.

Answer (score 0):

> Convert uint8_t to an ascii string C

Determine the maximum string size needed for any value of that type. [Is there a better way to size a buffer for printing integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028031/2410359)

```
#define UINT_BUFFER10_SIZE(type) (1 + (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)*LOG10_2_N)/LOG10_2_D + 1)
```

Form the buffer

```
char buf[UINT_BUFFER10_SIZE(value)];
```

"Print" the `uint8_t` to the buffer.

```
int len = sprintf(buf, "%d", value);
// or pedantically
int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%" PRId8, value);  // see <inttypes.h>
assert(len >= 0 && (unsigned)len < sizeof buf);
```

Send it

```
UART_write(uart, buf, len);
```

---

> how to log my int8_t variable

```
#define INT_BUFFER10_SIZE(type) (2 + ((CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)-1)*LOG10_2_N)/LOG10_2_D + 1)
char buf[INT_BUFFER10_SIZE(ivalue)];
int len = sprintf(buf, "%d", ivalue);
UART_write(uart, buf, len);
```

---

IMO, code should add a helper function to send a *string*

```
void UART_write_str(UART_Handle handle, const char *str) {
  UART_write(uart, str, strlen(str));
}
```